# Resetting the value of a UIStepper

Tags: swift, uistepper

I have a bunch of UIsteppers, and I have a button that resets them. I can set the labels to zero, but the internal count on the stepper doesn't change. I tried doing "stepper.value" but I'm getting the error "UIStepper has no member value"

```
@IBAction func colorlessStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
    colorlessLabel.text = String( Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func WhiteStepper(sender: UIStepper) {

    BlackLabel.text = String( Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func BlueStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
     BlueLabel.text = String( Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func redStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
     RedLabel.text = String( Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func greenStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
     GreenLabel.text = String( Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func blackStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
     WhiteStepper.text = String( Int(sender.value))
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    greenStepper.value = 0  //where I get the error
    BlackLabel.text = "0"
    BlueLabel.text = "0"
    RedLabel.text = "0"
    GreenLabel.text = "0"
    WhiteStepper.text = "0"
    colorlessLabel.text = "0"
}
```

Comment: How is `greenStepper` defined?

Comment: @Paul.s greenStepper it is probably just his IBAction method.

Comment: @user3015221 you will need to connect your UIStepper to an IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

You have greenStepper defined as an @IBAction.

You need to connect your stepper to an @IBOutlet to be able to edit its value property.

You're getting a confusing error message because of the naming conflict - you're attempting to edit the property of an @IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

Do this right before your `viewDidLoad()`

Connect your stepper with the assistant editor as an @IBOutlet.
So in your case it would be something like: `@IBOutlet weak var greenStepper: UIStepper!`

once you have done that and they have a connection.

do this in your reset button:

```
self.greenStepper.value = 1 // or whatever value you want
```